# What is the probability of drawing a number which is equal to the number of the draw?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am dealing with a problem right now. It sounds like this: assume that there are N papers with numbers throughout 1 to N in a box. Whenever one of them is drawn it is not put back in the box. What is the probability of drawing AT LEAST one paper which has the same number as the number of the draw?

What I tried: I tried visualising the problem and came to the conclusion that the first draw has the chance of 1/N. Although the second draw, if the first one failed, is equal to 1/(N-2). Things get complicated afterwards for me.

I would be grateful if you could provide me with a solution and an explanation, I'm new to this topic. Thanks!

Comment: The key term is [Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: I don't know the answer to this problem but I can say the solution is a little more complicated than that which you have set out. Say you draw a number from the box for the first time, and the number is not equal to $1$. Instead, let's say the number is $5$. That means on the fifth draw the number necessarily can't be $5$ as it has already been picked out. Your calculation does not take this into account. E.g. the second draw would actually have a $0$ chance of succeeding if the first number drawn was a $2$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbXg5EI5t4c

Comment: I think he means  5th no. draw 5 number card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing on its own can be looked at as drawing an element out of the set of permutations on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ in such a way that all $n!$ permutations are equiprobable, and to be found is then the probability of drawing a permutation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(i)=i$ for at least one $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

This probability equals $1$ minus the probability of drawing a permutation $\sigma$ that satisfies $\sigma(i)\neq i$ for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ which is by definition a so-called [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

The total number of derangements here is: $$!n:=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

So the probability that a derangement is drawn is: $$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$Then the probability that you are looking for is:$$1-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i!}$$

Comment: Notably, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, this probability approaches $1-1/e$.

Comment: noted in my numberphile link or the extra bit.

Answer (score 0):

Question : What is the probability of drawing paper $x$ on draw $x$ ? (drawing without replacement)

The probability of choosing the wrong paper on the first $x-1$ draws is

$${(N-1) \over N }.{ (N-2) \over (N-1)} . {(N-3) \over (N-2)} .... {(N-x+1) \over (N-x)} = {(N-x+1) \over N} $$

Given that we are on draw $x$ and paper $x$ still exists in the remaining stack the probability of choosing paper $x$ is then ${1 \over (N-x+1)}$.

Therefore, the probability of choosing paper $x$ on draw $x$ is $${(N-x+1) \over N} .{ 1 \over (N-x+1)} ={ 1 \over N}$$

Comment: This is not correct. See [Joe's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356156/what-is-the-probability-of-drawing-a-number-which-is-equal-to-the-number-of-the#comment6907511_3356156) to the question. The first disagreement happens at $n=3$ which gives a probability of $\frac23$ instead of $\frac13$ (the only failures occur for $231$ and $312$, two out of the six possible permutations).

Comment: @robjohn . Do you see an error in my short logic or no ?

Comment: Drawing paper x on draw x without replacement necessarily means you've missed paper x up to draw x-1. First, I gave the probability of missing paper x up to draw x-1. Second, the probability of choosing paper x on draw x WHEN YOU'VE MISSED PAPER X UP TO DRAW X-1. These events are obviously independent and thus their product is the desired probability.

Comment: If you miss the first paper, say it was $3$, on your $3^\text{rd}$ draw, you will not have $\frac{n-3}{n-2}$ probability.

Comment: @robjohn  1/(N-x+1) is the formula indicated in my original comment. What are you using to come to your conclusion ?

Comment: I am referring to ${(N-1) \over N }.{ (N-2) \over (N-1)} . {(N-3) \over (N-2)} .... {(N-x+1) \over (N-x)} = {(N-x+1) \over N}$ that has $(N-3) \over (N-2)$ as the probability of missing $3$ on the $3^\text{rd}$ paper.

Comment: incorrect. That formula as I stated gives the probability of missing x on the first x-1 draws ; of missing 3 on the first 2 draws.

Comment: As I explained we would then compute independently the probability of drawing paper x on draw x  *when you've missed it up to draw x-1*. It's all in the original post.

Comment: When computing the probability that you missed $3$ on the first two draws, you also need to also miss $1$ on the first draw and $2$ on the second; otherwise, you won't even make the third draw.

Comment: I think we're miscommunicating. The formula I posted was for P(x) the probability of drawing paper x on draw x. This formula is correct. P(x*) is P(x and (not x-1) and (not x-2) and...). These are two different probabilities. My answer was titled for P(x) not P(x*). The direct connection between the two I post below.

Comment: So this is not trying to answer to the original question; you should ask this in a separate question and not as an answer to this question. It is true that for any $x$, the probability of drawing paper $x$ on draw $x$ is $\frac1n$, but that doesn't seem to have much to do with the original question.

Comment: @robjohn. It has very much to do with the problem and I have posted the connection. I hope this clarifies our miscommunication.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)$ denote the probability of drawing paper $x$ on draw $x$. We've shown $P(x)=(1/n)$. Let $P(x^{∗})$ denote the probability paper $x$ is drawn on draw $x$ AND no smaller paper is drawn on its number. 
$$
P(x^{∗}) = P(x)\cdot\prod_{y\lt x}(1-P(y))=(1/n)\cdot(1-(1/n))^{x-1}
$$
where the product is taken over $y \lt x$.

The probability that at least one paper is drawn on its number is then the $\sum\limits_{x=1}^n P(x^{*})$ which yields $1-((n-1)/n)^n$.

Comment: For $n=3$, the answer is $\frac23$, but your formula gives $\frac{19}{27}\ne\frac23$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format questions and answers; it makes them much easier to read.

Comment: I have formatted with MathJax. Please check that everything still reads as you intended.

Comment: $\prod\limits_{y\lt x}(1-P(y))$ is valid only when the $P(y)$ are independent, which in this case, they are not. However, it is quite interesting that your formula does tend to $1-1/e$ as $n\to\infty$, just not as quickly as the correct formula.

Comment: @robjohn. Thank you again for the formatting. Still acquainting myself with the code but I see the dependence. I have a response regarding the convergence.

Answer (score 0):

drhab's answer is correct. In this answer, I simply use [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count the number of non-derangements.

Without changing the trials, assume the papers are stacked randomly in the box and we draw the top paper from the box.

We will use Inclusion-Exclusion to compute the probability that at least one paper is at its proper position in the stack.

Let $S(k)$ be the event that paper $k$ is at its proper position; that is, paper $k$ is at position $k$ in the stack.

Because each paper has probability $\frac1n$ to be in a given position, $S(k)$ has probability $\frac1n$ for each $k$. There are $\binom{n}{1}$ choices for $k$, so the sum of singleton probabilities is
$$
\binom{n}{1}\frac1n=1\tag1
$$
Similarly, $S(j)\cap S(k)=\frac1n\frac1{n-1}$; that is, the probability that paper $k$ is in the proper position is $\frac1n$, and then the probability that paper $j$ is in its proper position is $\frac1{n-1}$. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ choices for $j$ and $k$, so the sum of the pair probabilities is
$$
\binom{n}{2}\frac1n\frac1{n-1}=\frac1{2!}\tag2
$$
For the intersection of $m$ of the $S(k)$, we have a probability of $\frac1n\frac1{n-1}\cdots\frac1{n-m+1}=\frac{(n-m)!}{n!}$ and there are $\binom{n}{m}$ choices for the $S(k)$, so the sum of the m-tuple probabilities is
$$
\binom{n}{m}\frac{(n-m)!}{n!}=\frac1{m!}\tag3
$$
Inclusion-Exclusion gives the probability of at least one paper being in the proper position to be
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m!}\tag4
$$